# React image change with slider (Not carousel)

Tags: reactjs

Good day!

I am working on a project in React where I have several images that look almost the same, but differ in some way. [Here are the four images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW3D2.jpg)

What I want to do is to have a slider that changes the image on slide. So the image essentially gets replaced with the next one "in place" - if that makes sense. Thus, it's not a carousel, because the image is not moving, it's being replaced by another image. [Here is a mock-up of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAXmW.jpg)

The images are maps with locations that change each year. So I want the user to see how the locations change without the image moving.

I hope this makes sense. Are there any libraries or principles I should look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You question is very vague. There are many ways to achieve what you want. From the tag you used i assume that you are using React? I've created a basic example on what it could look like.

One way is to position the images on top of each other and toggle the visibility/opacity, like so:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    imageIndex: 0,
  }
  
  setIndex = (e) => {
    this.setState({imageIndex: parseInt(e.target.value)});
  }
  
  render() {
  const {imageIndex} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="image-wrapper">
            <img style={{opacity: imageIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0}} src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0"/>
            <img style={{opacity: imageIndex === 1 ? 1 : 0}} src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/f00"/>
            <img style={{opacity: imageIndex === 2 ? 1 : 0}} src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/f0f"/>
            <img style={{opacity: imageIndex === 3 ? 1 : 0}} src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0f0"/>
          </div>
          <input
              type="range"
              value={imageIndex}
              min="0"
              max="3"
              onChange={this.setIndex}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.image-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 150px;
}

html,
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Another way would be to render the image that is currently shown to the user, which can make animation handling a bit iffy, as unmounting needs to be delayed (in that case you should take a look at a React Animation Framework, e.g. [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/)) The image should be positioned with css in a way that it does not move.

I hope you can salvage something from this answer.

Comment: Hi @NickG, I appreciate your answer. I will give it a try, thanks!